# Scrollable div fill available height

Tags: css, height, overflow, scrollable

iam currently trying to create a "split view" site with a scrollable navigation bar on the left side and a content area on the right.

The navigation area on the left contains a search field (with a submit button) and below there is a scrollable tree view similar to windows explorer.

I looked around and found solutions for scrollable divs and divs that fill the rest of the height in a window but combining those gives me some headache

Iam looking for a solution without absolute positioning because the created page will be embedded somewhere else where this would break things.

Here is a demo of what i tried so far: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Aesgk/

As you can see, instead of 2 scrollbars as intended, i get a third one on the right because the navigation area's height.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Try this CSS

```
height: 100%
overflow: scroll
```

Comment: Thanks! Just tried it and it does not work :( As i have already overflow:auto which adds scrollbars if needed (as in my demo) changing it to overflow:scroll will only force the scrollbars to always be there.